# Having problems with my if statement/call thing, help please :)

Tags: python

Im having some problems with my code, take a look at the main() part, i type in choice 2
and it calls open_file. But it takes 1 as else and not IF… And when i write in 1 agin it just
prints 1 on the screen, what am i doing wrong? Python Version 3.4.2.

```
import sys
name=input("What is your name? : ")
print ("Welcome " + name)


def main():
    print ("What do you want to do")
    print ("1) Open A File")
    print ("2) open Web Browser")
    print ("3) Exit OS")

    main_choice=input()

    if main_choice == 1:
        open_file()
    elif main_choice == 2:
        web_browser()
    elif main_choice == 3:
        exit_os()
    else:
        unknown_number()


def unknown_number():
    print ("The choice you made does not exist, please choose a valid option")
    main


def open_file():
    print ("What do you want to do?")
    print ("1) Open A File TXT FILES ONLY")
    print ("2) Back to main menu")

    open_file_choice=input()

    if open_file_choice == 1:
        open_file_confirm()
    elif open_file_choice == 2:
        main()
    else:
        unknown_number()

def open_file_confirm():
    file=open("","r")
    print ("What is the file name? Include extension")
    file=input()

main()
```

Comment: Aside: you may find [this question](http://sopython.com/canon/8/prompting-the-user-for-input-until-you-get-a-valid-response/) useful reading.  (PS: `main` by itself doesn't do anything-- you want `main()` -- but that may not be a good idea to start with, as explained in the link.)

Comment: Note that you can accept the best answer to your question by clicking the tick outline to the left of their post, no matter what your reputation.

Answer (score 7):

`input()` produces a *string*. You need to convert that to an integer first:

```
main_choice = int(input())
```

or compare against strings instead.

You probably want to look over [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more tips.

Comment: @GameRight: Like this -- `if main_choice == '1':`, etc.